# Continue server side processing on .netcore IIS (migration stuff)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

I have a project where users upload multiple 4-6MB AccessDb files to migrate into a AWS hosted SQL Server database.  I think what is happening is that IIS maybe shutting down the process after some amount of time.

Its basically a file upload and then a c# static class that reads the `mdb` file and uses EF .core to copy into SQL Server.  Using Visual Studio, i don't see any shutdowns and all test files migrate successfully.

Website built using .netcore 2.1 / c#

I have `Web.config` timeout set to `requestTimeout="00:59:00"` so that basically stops some 503 errors.

What I'm seeing is that if all browsers are closed(or maybe not) and maybe technically no connections to IIS, that after a few minutes, the migration stops.  I'm not seeing new rows added to the database.

I want my c# .netcore processes to continue migrating whatever databases the user uploaded without IIS or whatever other process killing the connection.

Looking for tips I can update.  I'm assuming there's other Web.config settings I can update?

Comment: Is the server returning a response to the client and then processing the data? Or is it trying to do all that processing before it returns a response?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'm not seeing any response errors.  At first I got the 503 errors but that has since been corrected with the timeout extension.

Comment: Is it "straight up" copy or do you do some extra processing (hence EF) - re: essentially thinking bulk copy (instead).

Comment: I'll rephrase: When a user uploads the files, do they get a 200 OK back *before* the server begins processing the files? Or does that request remain open until the server is done processing the files?

Comment: @GabrielLuci I guess I'll have to look at the IIS logs to be sure but its a login webapp, the users goto a menu item to upload files.  I use a standard file upload /file stream to the server for a upload directory and the c# class picks up the file and starts the migration.  It "works" and 1-2 files or sometime more migrate just fine.

Comment: @EdSF it copies each file to a server folder then loops though each `mdb` file.  I'm using ODBC to read the AccessDb file and EF to copy as needed into SQL Server.

Comment: AWS Lambda is something more suitable https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your code that processes the files is a background job in your application, so I think I know what's going on.

By default, IIS app pools are configured to shut down after 20 minutes of inactivity (no incoming requests). You need to disable that.

The option is called "Idle Time-out (minutes)" in the Advanced Settings of the application pool. Set it to `0` to disable it.

There are also options in there to automatically refresh the app pool, so review those and make sure they are acceptable to you (I forget what the defaults are).

[image: App pool settings]

Comment: Thanks.  I checked those out and tested a bit.  However, cycling the AppPool didn't break the migration when I tested about an hour ago.  You think that could still help or be the cause?

Comment: Just got the following error:  `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.` Not sure if related.

Comment: Cycling the app pool may not, since it may be configured to start the app pool right away (that's the "Start Automatically" option in the screenshot). But if the idle timeout is set, then IIS will kill it if it hasn't received any requests for 20 minutes.

Comment: Ok, let me start clean and test this a bit.  I have multiple tabs open and I'll `iisrest` for good measure.  I'll post back my finding.  EF is slow so 3-4MB files take a few minutes to migrate.

Comment: Technically, this shouldn't be an issue right?  I should be able to spawn a worker process triggered by a user and whether they close their browser connection or not... even if all connections to the server are idle, it should continuing processing, right?  Short of IISreset, I'm hoping it would run as long as needed on the server.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm describing :) by default, it will not run as long as needed. IIS will kill your app after 20 minutes of not getting an incoming HTTP request unless you disable the "Idle Time-out".

Comment: So far so good.  6 files completed in 19 minutes.  Doing another test!

Comment: Kept getting 502 errors on next attempts.  Looking at the AppPool settings, I'm thinking I need to up the Max Worker Process up from 1 to I dunno... 10?

Comment: So you changed the idle time-out to 0?

Comment: More worker processes can complicate things since you have to make sure that each process isn't working on the same file.

Comment: You can follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log) to enable the log file in web.config, which may give you more information about why you're getting the 502.

Comment: Yes, I set the timeout to 0 and recycle to 0.  After the 6 files migrated successfully, i tried to do 10 more right after but the client browser came back with a 502 error after a few seconds.  Definitely progress!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good design decision to keep an http connection open for that long. First of all asp.net core will drop the thread after a while, and second the user could drop the connection by mistake. I would recommend doing this async to the user:

1. Receive the file, validate it.
2. Schedule a background job using either Hangfire or the builtin
   IHostedService interface.
3. When the migration is complete email or notify the user some other
   way.

Comment: I believe its doing this on its own.  I can start the import and close all browsers and it still chugs along.  Granted, i did set the AppPool Timeout to 0.  I'll take a peek at your suggestions though, thanks.